# How to set value in for-loop on laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, date, select

```
<select id="year" name="year" class="form-control ">
    {{ $last= date('Y')-120 }}
    {{ $now = date('Y') }}

      @for ($i ={{ $now }}; $i <= {{ $last }}; $i--)
         <option value="{{ $i }}">{{ $i }}</option>
      @endfor               
</select>
```

And I got the error message `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<'` 

It look like the variable can`t read.

How to set the value in the for-loop?

Comment: try this `@for ($i =$now; $i <= $last; $i--)`

Comment: in a blade template, anything inside the `@` directives (such as your `@for()`) will be treated as php, so there's no need to print it's value with `{{ }}`.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Basically `{{ $last= date('Y')-120 }}` in this part you are showing the value but you need to assign the value. So assign like this :

```
<?php $last= date('Y')-120; ?>
```

Same thing goes for the for loop too.Just compare the value. Do not put it in blade syntax.

```
<select id="year" name="year" class="form-control ">
    {{ $last= date('Y')-120 }}
    {{ $now = date('Y') }}

    @for ($i = $now; $i >= $last; $i--)
        <option value="{{ $i }}">{{ $i }}</option>
    @endfor
</select>
```

Answer (score 7):

using `@for ($i = $now; $i <= $last; $i--)` didn't work for me so I had to use **incrementing count**.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="task" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Text</label>
     @for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
       <div class="col-sm-12">
           <input type="text" name="text[{{ $i }}]" id="text[{{ $i }}]" class="form-control">
      </div>
     @endfor
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

The best way to do this is to use `range()` and `foreach()`

Example:

```
@foreach(range(date('Y')-5, date('Y')) as $y)
    {{$y}}
@endforeach
```

Result

```
2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019
```

Documentation:

- `range()` : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php

Answer (score 1):

Change your view to:

```
<select id="year" name="year" class="form-control ">
    <?php $last= date('Y')-120; ?>
    <?php $now = date('Y'); ?>

    @for ($i = $now; $i <= $last; $i--)
        <option value="{{ $i }}">{{ $i }}</option>
    @endfor
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write

```
<select id="year" name="year" class="form-control ">
    {{ $last= date('Y')-120 }}
    {{ $now = date('Y') }}

    @for ($i = $now ; $i <=  $last ; $i--)
    <option value="{{ $i }}">{{ $i }}</option>
    @endfor               
</select>
```

It will resolve your error.

Answer (score 1):

for days of the month you can do like so in laravel

```
<select class="form-control day-select">
   <option>Day</option>
      @foreach(range(1, 31) as $y)
        <option>{{$y}}</option>
      @endforeach
</select>
```

and for the years within a specified range say 1951 till date in descending order you can do

```
<select class="form-control">
   <option>Year</option>
   @foreach(range(date('Y')-16, date('Y')-70) as $y)
      <option>{{$y}}</option>
   @endforeach
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help.

```
<select id="year" name="year" class="form-control">
    {{-- */$last= date('Y')-120;/* --}}
    {{-- */$now = date('Y');/* --}}
    @for ($i = $now; $i <= $last; $i--)
    <option value="{{ $i }}">{{ $i }}</option>
    @endfor               
</select>
```

It will resolve you error, but would be nice if you pass your $last and $now variable from controller.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
    @foreach ($data as $item)
        @foreach ($order_item->where('order_id',$item->id) as $i)
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can simply use a forloop in blade file that's given below :

  ```
    <?php for($i = 0; $i < 6; $i ++){ ?>
       <span class="fa fa-star" style="color: #F2A057"></span>
    <?php } ?>
  ```